# jekyll - add stuff to pages automatically, on github pages

Tags: ruby, github, monkeypatching, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Is there a way to obtain the url of a **page** on Jekyll? By pages I mean non-post textile files, like `about.html` and `download.html` on the following hierarchy:

```
root
 |
 +- _includes
 |
 +- _layouts
 |
 +- _posts
 |
 +- _config.yml
 |
 +- index.textile
 |
 +- about.textile
 |
 `- download.textile
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<h1><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></h1>
```

This works with posts because they have their url included on [the post's to_liquid method](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/post.rb#L203). Pages on the other hand don't seem to include anything like it - they do have the properties I need (or so [it seems](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/page.rb)), but they don't export them on `to_liquid`; I'd like to redefine it so it does. Is there a way to do this?

I've found [jekyll_extensions](http://rfelix.com/2010/01/19/jekyll-extensions-minus-equal-pain/), but I don't know if it works on my target environment (github pages).

I'd like to avoid having to include a url parameter on all the yaml heads, if possible.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like page.rb to_liquid does now support the "url" data your need...

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/page.rb

Comment: yes it does. I modified the wiki myself in order to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is no. Here's [the Jekyll wiki](http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll/template-data) on what's in the global `page` item:

> For Posts, this is the union of the data in the YAML Front Matter and the computed data (such as URL and date). For regular pages, this is just the YAML Front Matter.

Even if you could reconfigure Jekyll's engine to do it for you locally, I'm not sure how you could make that work on Github's own Pages (since they will be using the vanilla Jekyll rather than yours).

Comment: damn. I wish it wasn't so... limiting. Thanks a lot, I guess I will just use the YAML (or create posts with fake dates, eg 0000-01-01)

Comment: One option is to generate the Jekyll _site/ files on your local system (you can have Jekyll modified as much as you want - including plugins). This is all in you're master branch. Then use Grancher (  http://timeless.judofyr.net/grancher ) to copy _sites/ to gh-pages branch, commit and push with a simple "rake publish" command.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to monkeypatch jekyll classes via its new plugins system!

Just add this file (page.rb) on your _plugins directory:

```
module Jekyll
  class Page
    def to_liquid
      self.data.deep_merge({
        "url" => File.join(@dir, self.url),
        "content" => self.content,
        "dir" => self.dir,
        "name" => self.name,
        "ext" => self.ext,
        "basename" => self.basename
      })
    end
  end
end
```

I've just modified `to_liquid` here, but I could have also added more methods, etc.